# Dynamic loading of nested swfs

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

AS3 newbie here. Hope I'm framing the question right.

**Background:**
I have a class called MultipleChoiceQuestion which pulls the stem and choices from an xml file. The choices for each question are randomized. The Quiz class has a set of specified multiple choice questions which it loads dynamically. It also references the xml file to determine # of questions. The quiz controls the question progression based on correct answers.  The main movie launches the quiz at the appropriate time.

**Issue**
I want the question building to be dynamic and load the choices and randomize them. How do I do this? Right now I publish the quiz as a swf and then load it into the main movie, but that is static and always has the same choices in the same order. How can I do this dynamically? 
Thanks in advance for your assistance!

[Heres a visual in UML](https://cacoo.com/diagrams/thJFe5r8gW96WR5x)

Comment: Could you show us some code of your XML parser? The part that generates the choices from the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create a Question class with an answers property which would hold all possible answers in an Array?

You could then randomize the possible answers by querying the Array with a random factor.

In this way, you wouldn't have to keep querying the XML, you'd end up with a set of Questions, which can generate their own multiples choices anytime you call the randomAnswers method.

```
   //In your Question class

   private var answers:Array;
   private var questionText:String;
   private var currentQuestions:Array;

   private function init():void
   {
        //Populate answers & questionText from the XML data
        // Then set your current choice of questions
        loadXML(xmlURL); // results in xmlLoaded...
   }

   private function xmlLoaded( event:Event ):void
   {
        //If you need 4 different answers
        currentQuestions = randomAnswers(4 );
   }

   // Set the number of answers required as a parameter
   private function randomAnswers( numAnswer:int ):Array
   {
        //The Array holding the set of random answers
        var ans:Array = [];

        //i've kept this basic for simplicity's sake
        //but you could remove a question that's already been stored
        //in order not to end up in some infinite loop...
        for( var i:int ; i < answers.length; ++i )
        {
              //set a random integer
              var rand:int = Math.random() * answers.length;

              //if the answer is not already stored, add it
              if( ans.indexOf( answers[rand] ) == -1 )
                 ans.push( answers[rand] );
              else // otherwise try again
                --i;
        }

        return ans;
    }
```

Without totally changing the structure of your game it should be possible to implement a randomize function triggered by the user input, i.e MouseEvent or whatever event triggers the slide you're referring to...

On the other hand, I get the impression from your description that your design is tied up to your content, which may be the source of your problem.

If it is the case, it should be possible to create Objects ( Question class ) that hold all the XML data ( slide , answers etc... ) and implement methods to randomize the data displayed.

In order to achieve that, you would need to load the XML data into these Objects, and the order of loading may not even be relevant... The idea being that you shouldn't be totally tied to the XML structure.

I can only guess here as I don't have a full overview of your application.

Comment: PatrickS: Thanks for answering and the coding. I have an shuffleArray function for randomizing. My issue is that the randomization only happens once when I'm publishing the quiz, but I need it to be dynamic when the main movie is loading.
  public function shuffleArray(passedArray:Array):Array {
   var arrayLength:Number = passedArray.length - 1;
for (var i:int = 0; i<arrayLength; i++) {
var roundNum:int = Math.round(Math.random() * arrayLength);
    var tmp:int = passedArray[i];
    passedArray[i] = passedArray[roundNum];
    passedArray[roundNum] = tmp;
   }return passedArray;}

Comment: Sorry it won't let me answer my own question and I can't put code in the comment.

Comment: The point wasn't so much about the shuffle function, but the possibility of loading your questions as classes after loading the xml data. Each Question would have its own possible answers, and you could shuffle those answers at anytime by calling a method.

Comment: Apologies for my misunderstanding. I guess that's where I get lost is loading the questions as classes. Not sure how to go about that.

Comment: You create a Question class, with at the minimum a variable to hold the question text and an Array or Vector to hold the multiple choices. When you load the XML data, simply parse the XML and create a bunch of Questions that you can hold in a Vector for instance. After this you can stop querying your XML and simply manipulate the Questions in any order you wish and call the shuffle method on the answers anytime you wish to.

Comment: Thanks again, PatrickS. I may be being obtuse on the root problem here. I have the questions load into a quiz as a class working fine. What I can't get my head around is, how do I then keep that quiz dynamic while using Quiz in its parent swf. 
So the user launches a module and clicks through slide by slide with slide content coming from an XML. They get to the quiz section. Right now I've got it as a static swf but I want the quiz to be dynamically created when the user hits that slide in the main movie. Hope I'm making sense :)

Comment: So, I assume I'd use the Quiz class in similar fashion to how I used the Question class in the Quiz by importing the Quiz class into the main.as file. But then when it's quiz slide, I don't know how to load a quiz dynamically as I'm pulling slide content from a separate XML. I believe the LoaderMax will allow the innermost xml parsing to be handled first (questionbuilding) and then work outward to Quiz and then Module (using the 'requireWithRoot:root' property).